# Periodic Orbits of the MacKay Map

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, nonlinear, difference-equations, periodic-function

For the MacKay (Henon action-angle transformation) Map [(Mackay 1983)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0167-2789(83)90131-8):

$x_{n+1}=q-\alpha x_n-x_n^2-y_n \\ y_{n+1}=x_n$

with $q, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ real parameters I would like to calculate the points which compose periodic orbits of period $m$. With a collaborator we wrote the following piece of code which calculates those pairs of points.

```
periodic[period_, initvalx_, initvaly_] := 
With[{q = 2.382163 - 2*0.8390658634208773 - (0.8390658634208773)^2}, 
Module[{x, y, val, valx, valy, init, eqn}, 
x = Table[Symbol["x" <> ToString@i], {i, period}]; 
y = Table[Symbol["y" <> ToString@i], {i, period}]; 
val = Join[x, y]; init = Array[0 &, {2*period, 2}]; 
init[[1]][[2]] = initvalx; init[[1 + period]][[2]] = initvaly; 
Do[init[[i]][[1]] = x[[i]]; 
init[[i + period]][[1]] = y[[i]], {i, period}]; 
Do[init[[i + 1]][[2]] = 
q - 2*0.8390658634208773*init[[i]][[2]] - 
init[[i + period]][[2]] - init[[i]][[2]]^2; 
init[[i + period + 1]][[2]] = init[[i]][[2]], {i, period - 1}]; 
eqn = Array[0 &, 2*period]; 
eqn[[1]] = 
q - 2*0.8390658634208773*x[[1]] - y[[1]] - x[[1]]^2 - x[[2]] == 0;
eqn[[period + 1]] = x[[1]] - y[[2]] == 0; 
Do[eqn[[i + 1]] = 
q - 2*0.8390658634208773*x[[i + 1]] - y[[i + 1]] - x[[i + 1]]^2 -
x[[i + 2]] == 0; 
eqn[[i + period + 1]] = x[[i + 1]] - y[[i + 2]] == 0, {i, 
period - 2}]; 
eqn[[period]] = 
q - 2*0.8390658634208773*x[[period]] - y[[period]] - 
x[[period]]^2 - x[[1]] == 0; 
eqn[[2*period]] = x[[period]] - y[[1]] == 0; 
sol = FindRoot[eqn, init]; val = val /. sol; 
valx = Array[0 &, {period}]; valy = Array[0 &, {period}]; 
Do[valx[[i]] = val[[i]]; 
valy[[i]] = val[[i + period]], {i, period}]; 
ListPlot[Table[{valx[[i]], valy[[i]]}, {i, period}]]]]
```

Although it works very well, we face the following issues:

- For a periodic orbit of period $m=5$ we get the following points:

  ```
  {x1 -> 0.114092, x2 -> -0.31857, x3 -> 0.319023, x4 -> -0.31857, 
  x5 -> 0.114092, y1 -> 0.114092, y2 -> 0.114092, y3 -> -0.31857, 
  y4 -> 0.319023, y5 -> -0.31857}
  ```

  and the correspoding listplot is the following: 
  (cannot upload due to some Imgur error)

but for a period of $m=10$ for the same initial conditions we get:

```
    {x1 -> 0.244737, x2 -> -0.375863, x3 -> 0.244737, x4 -> -0.0947348, 
    x5 -> -0.0947348, x6 -> 0.244737, x7 -> -0.375863, x8 -> 0.244737, 
    x9 -> -0.0947348, x10 -> -0.0947348, y1 -> -0.0947348, 
    y2 -> 0.244737, y3 -> -0.375863, y4 -> 0.244737, y5 -> -0.0947348, 
    y6 -> -0.0947348, y7 -> 0.244737, y8 -> -0.375863, y9 -> 0.244737, 
    y10 -> -0.0947348}
```

Which are the same points repeating themselves after $(x_5,y_5)$ with list plot of five and not ten points, as it should be.
I am guessing this has to do with `FindRoot` function of *Mathematica*, as apparently the corresponding non-linear system of equations ($a  \times 5$ in this particular case) accepts this set of solutions multiple times. Therefore that is not an actual period $m=10$ but a period $m=5$.

How could it be possible to tell *Mathematica* to not accept this as a solution and show only the period $m=5$? In this case it is easy to see by eye, but when I search for e.g. period $m=232$ this is not easy to deal with. I am thinking it would require a logical condition, but I am not yet able to implement something like that.

- Also, is it possible to tell *Mathematica* to show the results as pairs of $(x_i,y_i)$ and not in the way it does (first all $x_i$ and then all $y_i$)? Because this way it is hard to connect each pair, especially when the number of periodic points is large.

Thanks!

Comment: That is a lot of code, all written in very procedural style. Could you perhaps explain your algorithm in general terms? Perhaps there are easier ways to achieve your goal.

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you for your comment. I am trying to do exactly what I mention, find a 10-cycle which is not a 5-cycle and in general an m-cycle which is not an m/2-cycle. You can see in my example, FindRoot thinks of 10 pairs of solutions to the system of equations while it's just 5 of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Progress can be made as follows.  First, define

```
q = Rationalize[2.382163 - 2*0.8390658634208773 - (0.8390658634208773)^2, 10^-16]
α = Rationalize[2*0.8390658634208773, 10^-16]
f[{x_, y_}] := {q - α x - x^2 - y, x}
(* -(30/120000011) *)
(* 94448583/56281984 *)
```

where `q` and `α` are `Rationalize`d for improved accuracy at larger `m`.

**Obtaining all periodic orbits for small m**

To gain insight, next compute some small `m` periodic orbits.  Not surprisingly, there are two `m == 1` results.

```
Collect[Nest[f, {x, y}, 1], {x, y}, Simplify];
Solve[% == {x, y}, {x, y}, Reals] // N
(* {{x -> -6.79693*10^-8, y -> -6.79693*10^-8}, {x -> -3.67813, y -> -3.67813}} *)
```

There are no additional periodic orbits for `m == 2`.  For `m == 3`, however,

```
Collect[Nest[f, {x, y}, 3], {x, y}, Simplify];
Solve[% == {x, y}, {x, y}, Reals] // N
(* {{x -> -2.01472, y -> -2.01472}, {x -> -2.01472, y -> 1.33659}, 
    {x -> -1.01472, y -> 0.336588}, {x -> 0.336588, y -> -1.01472}, 
    {x -> 0.336588, y -> 0.336588}, {x -> 1.33659, y -> -2.01472}, 
    {x -> -3.67813, y -> -3.67813}, {x -> -6.79693*10^-8, y -> -6.79693*10^-8}} *)
```

in other words, the two `m == 1` solutions plus two `m == 3` periodic orbits.

```
NestList[f, {x, y} /. %[[1]], 2]
(* {{-2.01472, -2.01472}, {1.33659, -2.01472}, {-2.01472, 1.33659}} *)
NestList[f, {x, y} /. %%[[5]], 2]
(* {{0.336588, 0.336588}, {-1.01472, 0.336588}, {0.336588, -1.01472}} *)
```

Note that each periodic orbit contains at least one element in which `y == x` to roundoff.  Periodic orbits for other small `m` exhibit the same behavior, which is useful in computing results for larger `m`.  For instance, for `m == 5`,

```
Nest[Collect[f[#], x, Simplify] &, {x, x}, 5];
x /. N[Solve[PolynomialGCD @@ (% - {x, x}) == 0, x, Reals]]
(* {-3.67813, -6.79693*10^-8, -3.39749, -0.0947348, 0.114092, 0.765007} *)
```

in other words, the two `m = 1` periodic orbits plus two `m == 5` periodic orbits.

```
NestList[f, {#, #}, 4] & /@ %[[3 ;;]]
(* {{{-3.39749, -3.39749}, {-2.44401, -3.39749}, {1.52568, -2.44401}, {-2.44401, 1.52568}, {-3.39749, -2.44401}}, 
    {{-0.0947348, -0.0947348}, {0.244737, -0.0947348}, {-0.375863, 0.244737}, {0.244737, -0.375863}, {-0.0947348, 0.244737}}, 
    {{0.114092, 0.114092}, {-0.31857, 0.114092}, {0.319023, -0.31857}, {-0.31857, 0.319023}, {0.114092, -0.31857}}, 
    {{0.765007, 0.765007}, {-2.63402, 0.765007}, {-3.28285, -2.63402}, {-2.63402, -3.28285}, {0.765007, -2.63402}}} *)
```

(Comparing the elements of the four periodic orbits indicates that only two of the four are distinct.)  The same can be done for `m == 10`, although the computation takes about a minute.

```
Nest[Collect[f[#], x, Simplify] &, {x, x}, 10];
x /. N[Solve[PolynomialGCD @@ (% - {x, x}) == 0, x, Reals]]
(* {-3.67813, -6.79693*10^-8, -3.39749, -0.0947348, 0.114092, 0.765007, 
    -3.67077, -3.63341, -3.62913, -3.45167, -2.39583, -2.31377, -1.99886, 
    -1.94355, -0.513838, -0.455277, 0.3894, 0.684764, 0.695785, 0.777747} *)
```

Comparing `m == 5` and `m == 10` results shows that the `m == 10` results include two `m == 1`, two `m == 5`, and seven `m == 10` periodic orbits.  (The rest are redundant.)  For instance,

```
ListPlot[NestList[f, {x, x} /. x -> %[[19]], 9], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**Obtaining individual periodic orbits for large m**

The approach described above, although both comprehensive and elegant, becomes slower for progressively larger `m`, and eventually is prohibitively slow.  Then, one must revert to `FindRoot`.  However, as seen above, guesses with `x == y` can be used without loss of generality, and the majority of periodic orbits obtained will be of period `m`, rather than periods that are prime factors of `m` or one.  As an example, an `m == 10` periodic orbit can be obtained by

```
FindRoot[Nest[f, {x, y}, 10] == {x, y}, {x, 0.7}, {y, 0.7}, Evaluated -> False]
NestList[f, {x, y} /. %, 9]
Length@Union[%, SameTest -> (Norm[#1 - #2] < 10^-4 &)]
ListPlot[%%]
(* {x -> 0.843047, y -> 0.1883} *)
(* {{0.843047, 0.1883}, {-2.31377, 0.843047}, {-2.31377, -2.31377}, 
    {0.843047, -2.31377}, {0.1883, 0.843047}, {-1.1945, 0.1883}, 
    {0.3894, -1.1945}, {0.3894, 0.3894}, {-1.1945, 0.3894}, {0.1883, -1.1945}} *)
(* 10 *)
```

[image]

The third line of code above returns the order of the periodic orbit, in this case `10`, as desired.  If `5` or `1` had been returned, it would have been necessary to try another guess, again with `x == y`.

**Addendum: Obtaining all periodic orbits for broader range of small m**

The second and fourth values of `x` in the `m == 5` periodic orbits suggests that equating the symbolic expressions for these elements would provide an alternative, computationally more efficient approach to obtaining `y == x` elements.  More generally, the `y == x` elements satisfy the recurrence relation

```
{a[-1] == x, a[0] == x, a[n + 1] + a[n - 1] == q - α a[n] - a[n]^2, 
    a[m - 1] == x, a[m] == x}
```

It is evident from the symmetry of this system that `a[n] == a[m - n - 1]`.  Hence, for even `m`, `x` should satisfy symbolic expression for `a[m/2] ==  a[m/2 - 1]` and, for odd `m`, `a[(m + 1)/2] == a[(m - 3)/2]`.  Because the order of the polynomial represented by `a[n]` is given by `2^n`, these equations offer a significant advantage over those given in the first section of this answer.  As examples, for `m == 16`,

```
x /. Solve[Nest[f, {x, x}, 8][[1]] == Nest[f, {x, x}, 7][[1]], x, Reals] // N
```

yields 44 solutions in about 22 seconds, while for `m == 17`

```
x /. Solve[Nest[f, {x, x}, 9][[1]] == Nest[f, {x, x}, 7][[1]], x, Reals] // N
```

yields 102 solutions, although only after 31 minutes.  Hence, `m == 16` appears to be the practical limit for this alternative approach.  For larger `m`, obtaining individual periodic orbits with `FindRoot` seems necessary.  For completeness, below is a plot of the nineteenth periodic orbit for `m == 16`, determined from the equation immediately above.

```
ListPlot[NestList[f, {x, x} /. x -> %[[19]], 16], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**Response to Comment on very large m**

In a recent comment below, the OP asked about the applicability of my large-m procedure to `m == 4181`.  Here are some results.

```
FindRoot[Nest[f, {x, y}, 4181] == {x, y}, {x, 0.09, .1}, {y, 0.09, .1}, Evaluated -> False]
a4181 = NestList[f, {x, y} /. %, 4180];
Length@Union[%, SameTest -> (Norm[#1 - #2] < 10^-5 &)]
(* {x -> -0.0391555, y -> 0.048953} *)
(* 4181 *)
```

Note that the secant method is used here, because it is more robust for large `m`.  I have found other instances as well using the same code but with different initial guesses.  Each takes only few seconds.

- b4181: `{x, 0.08, 0.09}, {y, 0.08, 0.09}` yields `{x -> 0.0900303, y -> 0.0800034}`
- c4181: `{x, 0.19, 0.20}, {y, 0.19, 0.20}` yields `{x -> 0.112999, y -> 0.166375}`
- d4181: `{x, 0.192, 0.193}, {y, 0.192, 0.193}` yields `{x -> 0.192852, y -> 0.192912}`
- e4181: `{x, 0.13, 0.14}, {y, 0.13, 0.14}` yields `{x -> -0.170454, y -> 0.344412}`

`ListPlot[{a4181, b4181, c4181, d4181, e4181}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, AspectRatio -> 1]`

[image]

Incidentally, it appears that most successful computations for very large `m` produce m-cycle maps, as opposed to n-cycle maps, where `n` is a factor of `m`.  (Here, factors are `37` and `113`.)  On the other hand, `FindRoot` is not always successful in finding a closed map.

Comment: So I just had an unlucky initial guess in my `FindRoot` when `m=10` then?  I should have looked harder!

Comment: @ChrisK  That's correct.  If `FindRoot` converges, the odds are 8/11 that the periodic orbit will be order 10.  I suppose that I could have answered the question with just the last paragraph or so of my actual answer.  However, I wanted to develop an alternative approach to finding the orbit and was largely successful.  Probably, I shall improve the answer tomorrow by reducing the running time.  Best wishes.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Please excuse me for my late answer. Your answer provides a good solution for low orbit cycles. I am more interested into higher $m$-cycles, like we calculated a periodic orbit of $m=4181$ for this map and we would like to be sure that it is indeed of that period. Anyway, thank you so much for your time and help!

Comment: @Mitscaype  `{x -> 0.121173, y -> 0.177646}` yields a `253` cycle, and `{x -> -0.0562011, y -> 0.26327}` yields a `4181` cycle.  Interesting, their curves look very similar.  On the other hand, `{x -> 0.0149531, y -> 0.17865}` yields a `935` cycle which looks nothing like the other two.  Thanks also for accepting my answer.

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't really address OP's question, but in response to @MarcoB's comment, here's a much easier way to simulate the dynamics and find cycles based on [`Nest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html):

```
q = 2.382163 - 2*0.8390658634208773 - (0.8390658634208773)^2;
α = 2*0.8390658634208773;

(* define map *)
f[{x_, y_}] := {q - α x - x^2 - y, x};
```

You can use [`NestList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html) to simulate the dynamics easily:

```
NestList[f, {0.114092, 0.114092}, 5]
(* {{0.114092, 0.114092}, {-0.318571, 0.114092}, {0.319024, -0.318571}, {-0.31857, 0.319024}, {0.114092, -0.31857}, {0.114092, 0.114092}} *)
```

[`Nest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html) just gives the final point, so we can make an `m`-step ahead map using it:

```
(* m-step ahead map *)
ff[{x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ}, m_] := Nest[f, {x, y}, m]
```

To find an `m`-period solution, use [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html):

```
FindRoot[ff[{x, y}, 5] == {x, y}, {x, 0.1}, {y, 0.1}]
(* {x -> 0.114092, y -> 0.114092} *)
```

However the main question remains:

```
cyc = FindRoot[ff[{x, y}, 10] == {x, y}, {x, 0.1}, {y, 0.1}]
(* {x -> 0.114092, y -> 0.114092} *)

ListPlot[NestList[f, {x, y} /. cyc, 10]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Of course, a 5-point cycle is a 10-point cycle as well, so you need a different initial guess to find another, real 10-point cycle.  Without delving into the paper, I wonder if there necessarily even is an `m`-point cycle for arbitrary `m`?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this piece of code. So you are saying there is no way around this issue? A 10-cycle is easy to see but when I try to approach the last KAM curve of the map, where I have a sequence of m-cycles things get hard to see just by observing. Btw, the answer to your last question is that it has to do with the ICs which you impose.

Comment: @Mitscaype There very well could be a way around this issue, but I don't know it.  Just wanted to provide a cleaner way to simulate the model.  Maybe someone else will weigh in!

Comment: Ok then, thank you again :)