# Computing periodic points of some function

Tags: equation-solving, difference-equations, periodic-function

Given a function `h[{x_, y_}, b_, c_] := {x^2 + c - b*y, x}` for some parameter values `b` and `c` I would like to find periodic points. To do this for `b=0.01`, `c=-1` I have been using the following:

`NSolve[Nest[h[#, 0.01, -1] &, {x, y}, 2] == {x, y}, {x, y}]]`

which computes the period two points and, of course, we can change the `2` to our desired period. However, this is not really suitable for computing points of higher period, it is very intensive. Is there a way to make this more efficient so I could compute, say, points of period ten?

[This question seems related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138860/periodic-orbits-of-the-mackay-map) but my parameters may be complex and the periodic points may also be complex. Perhaps using the relation $x_{j + 2}=x_{j + 1}^2 -1- 0.01*x_j$ things may compute more efficiently, as in the linked question.

NB: Here I am not interested in the stability of the points, I would just like to find all, or as many as possible, periodic points of a given period.

Comment: Have you tried using FindRoot?

Comment: @Dominic, I have but the problem is FindRoot finds individual solutions while I'm looking for all, or as many as possible, solutions. FindRoot also slows down when you start dealing with points of high period, as with NSolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of recursively determine the period points, you could first iterate the function and subsequently determine the period points.

E.g. let us define the n-iterated function `fn[{x_,y_}]` for `{b,c}=={1/100,-1}` (note, it is better to use rational numbers if computing times allows):

```
hn[{x_, y_}] = Nest[Simplify[h[#, 1/100, -1]] &, {x, y}, n]
```

E.g. for n=2 :

```
h2{x_, y_}] = Nest[Simplify[h[#, 0.01, -1]] &, {x, y}, 2]
```

[image]

This gives the following period points:

```
Solve[h2[{x, y}] == {x, y}, {x, y}]
```

[image]

Up to `n==9` `hn` is  calculated rather fast, but `h10` suddenly takes much longer. The reason is not clear to me.

Comment: This seems to work well but `h9` doesn't seem to compute quickly. Maybe this is just due to hardware. I don't have any insight about `h10` vs `h9` other than `h10` will have twice the number of solutions of `h9`, perhaps that causes the slowdown.

Answer (score 1):

```
h[{x_, y_}, b_, c_] := {x^2 + c - b*y, x}
```

Nest until we find a result that we've seen before:

```
F[b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] :=
  NestWhile[h[#, b, c] &, {0, 0}, DuplicateFreeQ[{##}] &, All]
```

Try it out for given parameters:

```
f = F[0.01, -1]
(*    {-0.0203094, -0.989691}    *)
```

This seems to be a point with an orbit of size 2:

```
NestList[h[#, 0.01, -1] &, f, 2]
(*    {{-0.0203094, -0.989691},
       {-0.989691, -0.0203094},
       {-0.0203094, -0.989691}}    *)
```

Comment: This seems to give a single periodic point of some period. I'm trying to get all periodic points of, say, period 3 under the map. Is there a way to adapt this code for that purpose, or at least use it to find many other periodic points too?

Comment: Yes, the answer depends on the starting point. Are you looking for stable fixed points only, or also unstable ones?

Comment: I'm also interested in unstable points.

Comment: In that case, the method presented here does not work at all. Only stable points are found.

Comment: @math can you, please, update your question with this useful information? Thanks!

Comment: @CATrevillian, sorry, I thought this was clear from the question. I have updated to add this information.